# How to find proper codec for Xubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

I have just installed the Xubuntu. And I feel that to use it play a mp3 is like kill myself twice.

I try to play it with Exaile, the boxed player with Xbuntu. But it says I need to install some mpeg codecs.

I found so many depends with sudo apt-cache depends.

How to install them? one by one?!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing is to install a codec pack, copy the following in a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If you want DVD playback, execute the following in a terminal window after installing the codec pack:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Comment: Thanks BloodPhilia. I have successfully installed the xubuntu-restricted-extras, but the ubuntu "Movie Player" still asks me for mpeg-3 codec. What else do I need to do? Thanks again.

Comment: Try (installing and) using Totem or VLC.